# Foreach inside foreach than show it in HTML Table

Tags: php, foreach

Good day. I'm now trying to create detail that come from my sql table.

Here is My PHP:-

```
public function export()
    {
        $query = $this->input->cookie("cookie_invent_query");
        $data['header'] = $this->modelmodel->showdata($query);
        foreach($data['header'] as $header){
            $data['detail'][] = $this->modelmodel->showdata("select * from DeliveryOrderDetail 
                                                            where deliveryordertransno = '".$header->TransactionNo."' ");
        }
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($data['detail']);
        $this->load->view("do_mutasi/export",$data);
    }
```

with my script above i get tis in `print_r()`

result from `$data['header']`

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [FinalReleaseStatus] => 1
                [DeliveryOrderDate] => 2016-12-21 17:25:18.487
                [TransactionNo] => DO-DL-K-LFKG-11
                [DocumentNo] => DOZZ-DL-K-LFKG-6
                [ToCustomerCode] => AFF004
                [CategoryCode] => ZZ
                [ETADate] => 2016-12-21 17:25:18.487
            )

    )
```

result from $data['detail']

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [TransactionNo] => DOD-DL-K-LFKG-9
                    [LineNo] => 1000
                    [ItemCode] => FA00000111
                    [DeliveryOrderTransNo] => DO-DL-K-LFKG-11
                    [ExtraRemark] => 0
                    [ExtraRemark2] => 0
                    [Quantity] => 3.00000000000000000000
                    [UOMCode] => PCS
                    [CreatedDate] => 2016-12-21 17:26:25.063
                    [CreatedBy] => boby
                    [ModifiedDate] => 2016-12-21 17:26:25.063
                    [ModifiedBy] => 
                )

        )

)
```

then after i send it to my view and this what i can do for now

```
<?php foreach($header as $hdr) { ?>
 Header
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Trnsaction No</th>
                <th>Document No</th>
                <th>To Customer</th>
                <th>Delivery Order Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <td><?=$hdr->TransactionNo;?></td>
            <td><?=$hdr->DocumentNo;?></td>
            <td><?=$hdr->ToCustomerCode;?></td>
            <td><?=$hdr->DeliveryOrderDate;?></td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
Detail
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Transaction No</th>
            <th>Item Code</th>
            <th>Quntity</th>
            <th>Uom Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <?php 

     foreach($detail as $rsltdt =>$key) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$rsltdt['TransactionNo'];?></td>
            <td><?=$rsltdt['ItemCode'];?></td>
            <td><?=$rsltdt['Quantity'];?></td>
            <td><?=$rsltdt['UOMCode'];?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php } ?>
```

Asyou can see. I loop the `detail` inside the `header` loop. Because in some `records` there are multiple detail. I loop the header because i want to show it multiple `records` not just one `record`

here is the result so far

[image]

I can't show detail. So my question is. How can i show the detail depends on header.

`[TransactionNo]  = [DeliveryOrderTransNo]`

Comment: `foreach($detail as $rsltdt) { foreach ($rsltdt as $rsl){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$rsl->TransactionNo;?></td>
            <td><?=$rsl->ItemCode;?></td>
            <td><?=$rsl->Quantity;?></td>
            <td><?=$rsl->UOMCode;?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } } ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check once:-

```
foreach($detail as $rsltdt) { 
  foreach ($rsltdt as $rsl){ ?> 
    <tr> 
        <td><?=$rsl->TransactionNo;?></td> 
        <td><?=$rsl->ItemCode;?></td> 
        <td><?=$rsl->Quantity;?></td> 
        <td><?=$rsl->UOMCode;?></td> 
    </tr> 
<?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to put all details in its corresponding header :

```
public function export()
    {
        $query = $this->input->cookie("cookie_invent_query");
        $data['header'] = $this->modelmodel->showdata($query);
        foreach($data['header'] as $header){
            $data['header']['details'] = $this->modelmodel->showdata("select * from DeliveryOrderDetail 
                                                            where deliveryordertransno = '".$header->TransactionNo."' ");
        }
    }
```

then you can simply write the second loop :

```
 foreach($hdr['details'] as $rsltdt) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$rsltdt->TransactionNo;?></td>
        <td><?=$rsltdt->ItemCode;?></td>
        <td><?=$rsltdt->Quantity;?></td>
        <td><?=$rsltdt->UOMCode;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

You don't need to nest the details array anymore :

put:

```
$data['header']['details'] = $this->modelmodel->showdata("select * f....
```

instead of:

```
$data['header']['details'][] = $this->modelmodel->showdata("select * f....
```

Comment: I get this error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: @YVS1102  Updated the answer, try it!